# Auto-start the SQL Server Agent after a computer restart

Tags: windows-service, sql-server

I am using the `SQL Server Agent` to run some jobs every day, but the problem is that whenever the server (the machine itself) is restarted, the `SQL Server Agent` doesn't automatically start when the computer boots back up again...and I have to start it manually myself.

How can I set the Server Agent to Auto-Start after a computer restart?  
Is there a particular Windows Service I need to set as auto-start ?

Comment: Why are you restarting the server?

Comment: An update caused the server to restart

Comment: This is a good thing to monitor - make sure those agents are up!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Run services.msc, go to SQL SERVER AGENT service and set it on automatic start-up type

You can do the same thing by accessing sql server configuration manager that should be located in start/programs/microsoft sql server/configuration tools.

Comment: I just checked and the `SQLSERVERAGENT` job and it's already set to `Automatic`

Comment: The check the event logs to find out what happened.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check/ reset the **user account** that SQL Server Agent is using through SQL Server Configuration Manager (don't use services.msc) This will ensure correct permissions on files.
2. Check the Windows **event log** for any errors
3. Check the **SQLAGENT.OUT** file for any errors
4. Open SSMS and ensure that your **MSDB** database is there & functional

Answer (score 3):

1. Run Program: ***SQL Server Configuration Manager***
2. click on *SQL Server Services*.
3. Right Click on *SQL Server Agent* and click on *Properties*.
4. click on *Service* tab and set *Start Mode = Automatic*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it set to automatic after you reboot the server, do you get a popup box that says "A service did not start....." ?

If it is set to automatic, it should start and if it doesn't, or fails it will log it.

If something else is stopping it, that would also be logged.

Take a look in your Event log (right click my computer --> manage) Then in the Event log select system.  Go though these just after your reboot and see if anything mentions the SQL Agent.  It should show it starting then failing or stopping and "hopefully" why.

From there, google the message or post it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known circumstance to us with multiple versions of SQL Server, 2000, 2005, 2008 and I've concluded it's a bug.  We do monthly Windows patching on servers with about 50 instances, and typically we will have two or three which fail to restart the SQL Agent.  We also experience rare and random instances of SQL Agent stopping even without server reboots.  Typically there is no evidence in the error log or the agent log.  It just stops.

We have an SSIS package we developed to monitor servers and collect, centralize, and report Windows and SQL Server status info, space, size, growth,job failures, missing backups, security and config changes, etc.  One of it's features is to report status of all SQL Agent services.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible that the service may start and then stop if it detects that it has no works to do.  An alternative option would be to NET START it just before your daily job kicks in (I would do this anyway so as to ensure that it's up).

Comment: so u mean that I should set a schedule that net starts the job before the sql jobs start running ?

Comment: ...windows schedule, ie

Comment: The SQL Agent should start and remain running.  Its not a service that stops on it's own.

Comment: Agree with SpaceManSpiff (great name, btw!).  I've never seen the agent stop itself with no work to do.  It should sit there waiting for you to tell it to do something.